# Closed form for volume under $ f(x,y)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}\bigg) $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, closed-form, volume

I would like to find a closed form for the volume underneath $f(x,y)$ with $0<f(x,y)<1$ and $-1<x,y<1$: $$ f(x,y)=\exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\ln(x^2+y^2)}\bigg)$$

I know how to derive the closed form for a similar looking integral from this answer [Closed form for $\int_0^1 e^{\frac{1}{\ln(x)}}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158769/closed-form-for-int-01-e-frac1-lnxdx): $$ I:=\int_0^1 \exp\bigg(\frac{1}{\ln(x)}\bigg) ~dx =2K_1(2)$$ where $K_1$ is a modified bessel function of the second kind.

I can't seem to get the techniques found in the linked post to work for this function of two variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about the unit circle? Then $x^2+y^2=1$ and the function is undefined.

Comment: @QC_QAOA the integral can still exist, and indeed the integral on just the unit disk portion can be shown to be $2\pi K_1(2)$. The question becomes whether or not the integral converges outside of the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a response to the comments to the original question. First, consider the switch to polar coordinates

$$x=r\cos(t)$$

$$y=r\sin(t)$$

Then if the integral outside the unit circle converges if and only if

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_1^2\exp\left(\frac{1}{\log(r^2)}\right)rdrdt=2\pi \int_1^2\exp\left(\frac{1}{2\log(r)}\right)rdr$$

However, this integral does not converge according to Mathematica. Therefore, the original integral does not converge and we are done

Comment: Your premise is faulty. Consider the integral $$\int_{x^2+y^2\leq 1} \frac{1}{x+y}\:dA$$ This integral exists yet the integral along the line $y=x$: $$\int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{1}{2t}\:dt$$ does not converge.

Comment: Fixed and made clearer by changing to polar coordinates